# How to use JS lib in GWT via ScriptInjector?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I would like to use a javascript library in GWT.

I put the files in the public folder so it is shared between the client and the server and injected the javscript following this tutorial (https://pelle.io/2015/01/27/integrating-javascript-libraries-into-gwt-using-jsni/).

```
    StyleInjector.inject(INSTANCE.fullcalendarCSS().getText());
    StyleInjector.inject(INSTANCE.fullcalendarPrintCSS().getText());
    StyleInjector.inject(INSTANCE.schedulerCSS().getText());
    ScriptInjector.fromString(INSTANCE.jqueryJS().getText()).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
    ScriptInjector.fromString(INSTANCE.momentJS().getText()).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
    ScriptInjector.fromString(INSTANCE.fullcalendarJS().getText()).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
    ScriptInjector.fromString(INSTANCE.scheduleJS().getText()).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
```

Everytime I execute my javscriptcode I get an "not a function" exception.

```
   public static native void drawScheduler() /*-{

    var calendar = $doc.getElementById("calendar");
    calendar.fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
        events: [
            // events go here
        ],
        resources: [
            // resources go here
        ]
        // other options go here...
    });

}-*/;
```

Comment: what gwt version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `fullCalendar` is from a jQuery plugin, then DOM elements aren't modified; you need to wrap it in the jQuery "object" (generally `$(calendar)`, here it'd likely be `$win.$(calendar)`)